# In the TOC for the generated PDF of an R Notebook, section numbering and long heading text are garbled together. How can I fix it?

Tags: fonts, r-markdown, tableofcontents, rnotebook

I have an R notebook which is knitted to PDF. For log headings, the section numbering and the text kinda print on top of each other. The only solution so far which I do not appreciate is to switch the fonts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the YAML header fixed the issue. It looks like it is somewhat case-specific though. A different font and size may lead to say `7em` instead of `5em` for the `chapter` and so-on.

```
header-includes:
- \usepackage{titletoc}
- \dottedcontents{chapter}[5em]{}{3em}{1pc}
- \dottedcontents{section}[9em]{}{4em}{1pc}
- \dottedcontents{subsection}[13em]{}{4em}{1pc}
```